# Verify XML document using public key that is in the document

Tags: c#, xml, signature

I have managed to succesfully add a public key to the signature of the document. The goal is to verify it using that public key, and not use the certificate. Here is the XML in the signed doc:

```
<KeyValue> 
 <RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>t++UmV1G9ApuI118GdwK0BoxN3tjrxuQHTwKvlFgl6VrcLhMCb5Q2prga8I4HKLvLDr3L4bsrH0k9r6PPppqMpiN/KGdm6eB2uLnWtJXh1PWcnzfHfodYfQP/NAavIo4wSjss0L41c75/CA0x11iDdU4BOdTHGXaFCaNPQ5DLe3LK+6hjZ+fOYMpCd035TYTLo5+/Ttk5eCzr+MHfnWCaCIOUgkbq0OIUQWch2Sc9regIiA9oPPjUmmbqptLfm9wZBHRZZ+7Q4BewxSBBCIFt5yPhCsTZ1fFINV16tGtXTmtgXCagu4NiH7XsyhZhYDrA8CXb31Dn7M/ussNQkGrEQ==
   </Modulus>
   <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
 </RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
```

This is my app for verifying.

```
        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/GR-002/Desktop/xml_should_fail_validation.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

        X509Certificate2 pubCert = 
            new X509Certificate2(@"C:/Users/GR-002/Documents/DigitalSignature/base64_encoded_certificate.cer");

        Console.WriteLine(ValidateXmlDocumentWithCertificate(doc, pubCert));
    }

    public static bool ValidateXmlDocumentWithCertificate(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        try
        {
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
            return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
        }

        catch { return false; }
    }
```

Currently I am using the certificate. I want to change that to use the public key instead.

Comment: A key consists of two parts a private and public key.  The Private key is the same every time you use the certificate and is embedded in the application (both in client and server code) and should not be transmitted.  The public key is generated each time a certificate is generated.  So you need both keys and to test you would need to create a public key and generate a certificate with data and then reverse the process.

Comment: Ok. Two questions - how do I transfer the certificate in the XML? And how can I use that public key or it is already in the certificate?

Comment: You want to send certificate separate from application (like using email) so hackers cannot get the certificate and data from application encrypted from application.  The public key is the key the is used to sign the certificate.  The public key is generated from the private key. The private key is generated when the key class is constructed using a random variable that is either part of the constructor or random variable from a seed (like a string passed to the constructor).

Comment: jdweng thank you for your time. So I don't really need to attach the public key to the XML?

For security purposes, I only need to send the certificate to the user who wants to check if it is me who sends the message correct?

Comment: See Wiki example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509

Comment: What I need to do is get a batch of xmls, sign them with digital signature and zip them to a web service. Is there no way to do this automatically and send the certificate to the web service or they have to add it? I am confused.

Comment: It is fine to put a certificate on the web that does not have the private key.  The Wiki examples shows two different types certificates .  The private key should be sent to users in a secure fashion and only need to be sent once since the private key does not get changed.